# Laravel phpunit mock model first function

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to mock a model where I am doing a query on the db. At first I was mocking the `where` function on the below but then I realised it's actually `first` that provides the result, however this still doesn't work. I am aware I could just use the database, but our docker setup is super slow and I can't use SQLite as a previous developer created a migration at some point that removes a foreign key.

Test:

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->calendarEventBookingRepository = app(CalendarEventBookingRepository::class);

    $this->calendarEventBooking = Mockery::mock(CalendarEventBooking::class);
}

/** @test */
function bookSingleCustomerReturnsNull()
{
    $calendarEvent = factory(CalendarEvent::class)->create();
    $calendarEventBooking = factory(CalendarEventBooking::class);

    $data = new \stdClass();
    $data->customer_id = 1;

    $this->calendarEventBooking->shouldReceive('first')->once()->andReturn($calendarEventBooking);
    $this->app->instance(CalendarEventBooking::class, $this->calendarEventBooking);

    $result = $this->calendarEventBookingRepository->bookSingleCustomer($calendarEvent, $data);

    $this->assertEquals(null, $result);
}
```

Function being tested:

```
public function bookSingleCustomer(CalendarEvent  $event, $data)
{
    $this->event = $event;

    DB::transaction(function () use ($data) {
        $alreadyBooked = $this->modelClassName::where([
            ['customer_id', $data->customer_id]
        ])->first();

        if ($alreadyBooked) {
            return null;
        }

        return "hello";
    });
}
```

Test Output:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method first(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_Models_CalendarEventBooking should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

Comment: It is due to how Laravels orm is bound to a model, in my opinion it is a waste of time to mock laravel models, no one does it on a higher scale afaik. Usually there is two aproaches to deal with this, use sqlite as your test db and never hit a "correct" database which i prefer. Another aproach is to encapsulate your model logic in services or similar and then mock the service instead of the laravel models. I can help you achieve both if you want to go those routes :) Blatantly copy pasted from another post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should mock the where method as well.

```
$this->calendarEventBooking->method('where')->willReturnSelf();
```